# unable to get webElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i am trying to send the values to table sorter filter and then select the checkbox of that value .

But unable to get the webElement.

HTML: There are 4 filter box , need to send values to filterbox having index 1.

```
<tr class="tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow" role="row">
<td data-column="0">
<td data-column="1">
<input class="tablesorter-filter" placeholder="" data-column="1" data-lastsearchtime="1485173126687" type="search"/>
</td>
<td data-column="2">
<td data-column="3">
<td data-column="4">
</tr>
</thead>
```

need to send value to given textbox
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq1jM.png)

Comment: Show `stacktrace` or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
    //Get a list of all the checkboxes
    List<WebElement> listOfElements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow']/td"));
    //click on the text box of index 1.
    listOfElements.get(1).click();
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[@class'tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow']td/ because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tr[@class'tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow']td/' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I updated my answer, could you please try again? Didn't noticed that I wrote td/ where it should be /td

Comment: still the issue is persisting.org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[@class'tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow']/td because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tr[@class'tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow']/td' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Could you please try one more time?

Comment: it worked by giving explicit wait . thank you so much